# How to fetch selected version value in programming in Sitecore 9.1.1?

Tags: events, versions

When I will click in the Sitecore client to change versions, I would like to be able to run some code. So, Is there any event when I will select any version number in the Sitecore client? I am sharing screenshot from where I am selecting version. I need to get their value so i am able to run some code.

[image]

Comment: What "code"? A Sitecore Powershell ribbon button? A command?

Comment: I am talking about programming likewise -: item:versionAdded and item:version removed events. There we can get all the details.

Comment: So you mean that when a user clicks in the Sitecore client to change versions, you would like to be able to run some code. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, Matthew i want to run some code when user clicks in the Sitecore client to change versions